# Is it possible to get latest missed call or received sms notification from a class which we created on android?

Tags: android, class, sms

I am able to see getting new sms or calllog from apks which I built but my question is that;
for example I create a .class which in

```
<com.example.xx 
Can I use it on my any other apk's layout xml file using <com.example.xx ... /> using with layout width and height.
```

Is that possible? If so can you create this class file ? 
( I know manifest needs receiver and permissions for latest missed calls & messages)
I hope I can explain clearly what I mean

Comment: Im sorry It didnt show with normal text so read it again please. Im asking not in an activity just from a class which I can use directly in any app.

Comment: To use it in another apk's layout xml file, it would need to be in the same global scope. In other words, the two apks would need to be signed the same way by the same developer key and use the same package name (the application package name, not necessarily the Activiy package name). Or if the two apks are made by two different people, one would need to send it to the other as some kind of library that the other developer would import into his project.

Comment: Hmm. thank you for your all replyings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also not sure what you're asking, but...

Yes, you can access the latest sms or the call log from any Activity you want, from any apk you want, and/or from pretty much from anywhere you want on the phone.

You'd use a Content Provider to access that information. If you wanted to, you could even use a Broadcast Receiver to trigger your application whenever you received a message or phone call.

And yes, you could even do this in a library if you wanted (so that others could use it from their own layouts). If that's what you're asking.

And yes, you could even do this from one apk to another apk through intents if you wanted (not that I would see any advantage to doing that). May be, that last one is not what you were asking.

Have I answered your question?

Comment: Thank you so much for fast reply. First I am new to development and started with basics of android. I know I couldnt explained clearly but will try to explain again:

think about VerticalTextView.java its a .class file and I can use it main.xml or any xml by adding < com . xxx . VerticalTextView .. /> 
It was like that.